# How to add weightSum attribute for main LL?

Tags: java, android, positioning

In my Android app I need dynamically create few LinearLayout's with text.

But I can not set weight of each element. I want that LL looks like in XML part:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10px"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:id="@+id/qwe">
<TextView 
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="some"
/>
<TextView 
    android:layout_weight="0.8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="word"
/>
<TextView 
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="here"
    android:gravity="right"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

It looks good but I need the same dynamically.
In Java code I wrote:

```
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(context);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layoutParams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
ll.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
ll.setBackgroundColor(0xFF888888);
rootLL.addView(ll);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams params1 = params;
params1.weight = 0.15f;
TextView one = new TextView(context);
one.setLayoutParams(params1);
one.setText("some");
ll.addView(one);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams params2 = params;
params2.weight = 0.7f;
TextView two = new TextView(context);
two.setLayoutParams(params2);
two.setText("word");
ll.addView(two);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams params3 = params;
params3.weight = 0.15f;
TextView three = new TextView(context);
three.setLayoutParams(params3);
three.setText("here");
ll.addView(three);
```

But in this case I obtain three textView's with equal width. It looks that I did not add `weightSum` attribute for main LL but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. prefer integer over float . this way you can get any kind of fraction you wish (even 1/3) .
2. if you set the weight of each of the views , you don't need to set the weightSum .
3. if you set the weightSum , you can leave one view without any weight , giving it the rest of the space available.
4. it seems you give all of the views the same layoutparams instead of cloning it for each of them . when you use "params2 = params;" , it means that you set a reference to it and not that you create a new one . in the end of the method , all will point to the same layoutParams , with the weight of 0.15f (since that's the last one) .

Comment: Thank you for your replay! Your tips helped me. I mistake was in cloning of layoutparams. Everything is good when I created new one for each of TextView. Thank you!!!

Comment: you're welcomed , and i recommend you to watch google IO videos . they can give you plenty of other tips . for beginners , you can also watch "the new boston" videos.