# android loading icons equidistant separated by line

Tags: android, android-layout, view, line, android-linearlayout

I have a horizontal linearlayout which has fixed width. The view can have icons ranging from 2 to 6 at runtime in number.I want these icons to be at equal distance separated by line between them but they should occupy complete layout width.
E.g : 
If Linearlayout width = 100dp and icons = 4 i ll have 3 lines in between these 4 icons, separated at equal distance.Each line width would be (100 - 4*(icon width))/3

I have made 6 imageviews and 5 line views which i am trying to hide/expose at runtime based on data i get.
I have managed to make visible the right ones at runtime but i am unable to set width of separating lines accordingly.

This is what i have in LinearLayout

```
<LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">



        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_itinerary_mode_0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/iv_itinerary_next_0"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/lightgrey"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_itinerary_mode_1"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:visibility="gone" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/iv_itinerary_next_1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@color/lightgrey"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_itinerary_mode_2"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:visibility="gone" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/iv_itinerary_next_2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@color/lightgrey"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_itinerary_mode_3"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:visibility="gone" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/iv_itinerary_next_3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@color/lightgrey"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_itinerary_mode_4"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:visibility="gone" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/iv_itinerary_next_4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@color/lightgrey"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_itinerary_mode_5"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:visibility="gone" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/iv_itinerary_next_5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@color/lightgrey"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_itinerary_mode_6"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

Kindly suggest how to set this layout such that lines and icons set which are visible set at equal distance on their own at the same time occupying the width.

E.g Image :

[image]

Comment: you should create the layout at runtime instead of hiding unused views, once in code you can set the correct width for each view, or, you can use weights as pointed by @Mohit.

Comment: @Mohit can you suggest how to use weightsum?

Comment: I haven't used it programmatically but, [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848245/weightsum-xml-attribute-in-code-android) [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170164/android-setting-the-weight-parameter-programmatically-does-the-opposite-of-what) [link3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11611531/android-layout-weight-programatically) might help you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Mohit i solved it by giving weight to each line as 100 and to each imageview weight as 1. Though this doesnt go with the weightsum concept it worked for me.